# Can't display JSON on page

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have been trying to get my JSON code from a PHP file which is connected to my database to display on my website using an `XMLHttpRequest`, but we cant split them and display it.

We are using an php file example.php that does the following:

```
function jsonFromQuery($result) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $json[] = $r;
        }
    } else {
        $json = "Table is empty";
    }

    return json_encode($json);
}
```

This will display the json code as following on the website if you open the php file:

`[{"UserID":"2","Firstname":"Piet","Lastname":"Klaas","Age":"23","Specialization":"Voet","Branch":"Been","Interests":"Hoofd","Hospital":"OLVG","Email":"pietklaas@gmail.com","ProfilePicture":""}]`

With this we use the following javascript file to request this php file and stringify and try and display it.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open('GET' , 'http://myurl.nl/example.php', false);
request.send(null);

if (request.status == 0)
    console.log(request.responseText);

var obj = JSON.stringify(request);
var firstname = obj.Firstname;
document.writeln(firstname);`
```

But I get a massive string which includes the type status etc. And don't know how to split this up to display on their own. For example only Firstname = Piet on the page.

Comment: your json is already in string form, you dont need to stringify it, what you want is [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Why do you parse `XMLHttpRequest` instead of data you need? lol

Comment: You're going the wrong way... Stringify turns an object into a json string (serializes it), not the other way around. You wnat `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the data back from PHP it's already in the form of a string. You need to use `JSON.parse()` to convert it into an object you can use. Try...

```
var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
var firstname = obj[0].Firstname;
document.writeln(firstname);`
```

Note as well that the Json you're getting back is a list of objects: `[{...},{...},{...}]`, so you can't just call `.Firstname` as you haven't specified which object you care about. Hence the `[0]` in the example above to pick out the first object.

One other thought... At present if your PHP doesn't find any results it's going to send back something that isn't in the format you're expecting. Consider either wrapping the list in an object with a status...

```
{
    "Success": true,
    "Results": [{...}, {...}]
}
```

Or make the PHP script return a different HTTP code to indicate failure (404 seems appropriate here)

For future reference, JSON.stringify does the opposite - it takes a complex object and converts it *into* Json

Comment: Parse `request.responseText` instead of `request`

Comment: @Jan Nicely spotted, I hadn't checked that bit. Thanks/Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing the whole XMLHttpRequest object

`var obj = JSON.parse(request);`

try using just the response body

`var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);`

Comment: while he does need request.responseText, he will need `JSON.parse`, not `JSON.stringify` as it is already a string.